# Single line scrollable div containing iframes

Tags: html, css, vue.js

So I'm using Vue.js for my web development.

I've got to embed a control created by another developer on my page.
Its in an iframe and this is causing me hassle.

Code example below:

```
.simparent { margin: 1rem;  padding: 2rem 2rem; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:auto; }
.simblock { float:left; margin-right: 20px;} 


 <div class="simparent">                
    <div  v-for="ocs in simulations" :key="ocs.SimulationId" :value="ocs.SimulationId">  
        <div class="simblock">
            <iframe v-bind:src="`https://xxxxxx/?simulation=` + ocs.SimulationId " width="325" height="400" style="border: 0px;"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want a single row containing the controls. If it overflows the page I want a horizontal scrollbar. The problem is because the control is in an iframe, using inline-block doesn't work, I have to use float:left. Because of this, white-space:nowrap no longer works.

How do I get a single row of iframes that will show a scrollbar when too big to fit?

Comment: _"The problem is because the control is in an iframe, using inline-block doesn't work, I have to use float:left."_ - explain; what exactly does "not work" with inline-block?

Comment: How is this https://jsfiddle.net/za1jnvs2/ "not working"? (And even with the `v-for` div left in place, I don't know if vue actually removes that or not, it still works the same, https://jsfiddle.net/za1jnvs2/1/)

Comment: The iframes are appearing on separate lines. I'm starting to suspect its due to this bit of html being in a div that is below a load of other css styles. If I put your example on a new page it works, in the nested did it doesn't, so it has to be something messing it up...

Comment: Then inspect those elements, and see what styling actually applies in the given context. (Could be something as simple as your attempt to set `display: inline-block` getting overwritten by a more specific rule ... or something more complex. Without a proper example, hard to tell.)